# Login Authentication to Database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

Newly, I'm working with Xamarin Studio to build program using C#. I know this is quite simple question, but I really can't get it. I want to know what kind of code I have to use to authenticate login to MySQL Database. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow () : base ("RepSys ICDX 1.0 - Login")
    {
        SetDefaultSize (282, 142);
        SetPosition (WindowPosition.Center);
        DeleteEvent += OnDeleteEvent;

        Label uid = new Label ("Username\t: ");
        Label pass = new Label ("Password\t: ");

        Entry uide = new Entry();
        Entry passe = new Entry ();
        passe.Visibility = false;

        Button login = new Button ("Log-In");
        Button exit = new Button (Stock.Cancel);
        login.SetSizeRequest (75, 30);
        exit.SetSizeRequest (75, 30);

        Fixed fix = new Fixed ();
        fix.Put (uid, 20, 30);
        fix.Put (pass, 20, 60);
        fix.Put (uide, 100, 26);
        fix.Put (passe, 100, 56);
        fix.Put (login, 101, 90);
        fix.Put (exit, 186, 90);

        Add (fix);
        ShowAll ();

        login.Clicked += delegate {
            //What should I do here to authenticate user login???
        };
        exit.Clicked += delegate {
            Application.Quit();
        };
    }

    private void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp). The example is done by Visual Studio, but it should be no problem to do it with another IDE.

Your click handler needs to be modified:

```
login.Clicked += delegate {
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=testdb;Uid=<your user>;Pwd=<your password>");
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table;"
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
    reader.Close();
    command.Close();
    connection.Close();
};
```

Do not forget to add the using declaration:

```
using: MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

You also need to add `MySql.dll` (Win apps) and `MySql.web.dll` (Web apps) as references.

Comment: if you don't get this to work, you can have a skeleton app of mine